# Issue with displaying the image in an Apostrophe css widget

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm having difficulty displaying an image uploaded via an Apostrophe widget. Specifically I'm creating a 'hero' widget with a background image, title and description text over the top of the image. The widget seems to be working correctly as I can add title and description text in, but the image does not display. The error I am seeing in the command line is:

'Template warning: Impossible to retrieve the attachment url since it is missing, a default icon has been set. Please fix this ASAP!'

index.js for the widget:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    name: 'heroimage',
    label: 'Hero Image',
    addFields: [
        {
            name: 'hero-image',
            label: 'Hero Image',
            type: 'attachment',
            widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
            required: true,
            extensions: [ 'jpg', 'png' ],
            extensionMaps: {
              jpeg: 'jpg'
            },
            // uploadfs should treat this as an image and create scaled versions
            image: true,
            options: {
                minSize: [ 1280, 900 ],
                limit: 1,
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'hero-title',
            label: 'Hero Title',
            type: 'area',
            options: {
                widgets: {
                    'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                    controls: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink' ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'hero-description',
            label: 'Hero Description',
            type: 'area',
            options: {
                widgets: {
                    'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                    controls: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink' ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

widget.html:

```
<div class="hero align-center-middle text-center"
    style="background: url('{{ apos.attachments.url(image.attachment) }}'); background-size:cover; background-position:center;">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
        <div class="cell">
            <h1>
                {{ apos.area(data.widget, 'hero-title') }}
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <p>
                {{ apos.area(data.widget, 'hero-description') }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried every combination of code inside the '{{ apos.attachments.url(image.attachment) }}' but nothing seems to work. Have I done this correctly, is there something I am missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Is `image` a nunjucks variable your creating elsewhere? Hard to tell from your snippet. My first thought is that you should pass `data.widget.hero-image` to the url helper.

Try logging the data your passing to the helpers like `{{ apos.log(image) }}` to make sure you have something at all.

Comment: hero-image is the nunjucks variable. I've tried using 'data.widget.hero-image' to the url helper and '{{ apos.log(image) }}', but I am still getting the 'impossible to retrieve the attachment url' error.

Comment: Seems to be working when using this - {{ apos.attachments.url(data.widget['hero-image'], { size: 'full'}) }}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use hyphens in schema field names. It just makes them harder to work with by forcing the use of the bracket syntax. Also it is disallowed entirely for a few other property types. Use camel case:

```
{
  name: 'heroImage',
  // etc.
}
```

Second, you are using the variable "image" in your `widget.html` template but it is not being assigned from anywhere, so it is undefined. If you want access to a property of the widget, you need to reference it as a property of the widget:

```
data.widget.heroImage
```

Once you do that everything should work out fine.

Third: `extensionMaps` is a feature for configuring the attachments module itself, it has no effect here. And `extension` is not an option in this situation either. You can set `group` to `images` (which allows GIF, JPEG or PNG) or to `office` (which allows a range of office-related formats like txt or pdf).

Comment: Ah I see what I've done incorrectly. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Please upvote the answer so it is accepted. Thanks.